# ASP.NET using JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Basically I'm creating a slideshow in Jquery, Following this guide > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yikHrIMsccw

It asks me to input

```
<body onload="Script();">
```

into my page, but I can't, due to the fact I'm using a MasterPage for my layout then Content Pages.. I tried adding the code into Masterpage but it complained that I had more than one body, so I removed the original body, leaving just  but still didn't work..

When I try entering it into my Content Page, it stats that I can't place the  into a ContentPlaceHolder header, so I move to my second ContentPlaceHolder and it still doesn't work..

Please help me resolve this issue, would be greatly appreciated!

**BIG THANKS TO THOSE THAT SUPPORTED ME!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        Script();
 });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, where would I place that?

My Current code is >

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Slider() {
            $(".slider#1").show("fade", 500);
        }
    </script>

& 

<body onload="Slider();"> should be within the Body, but placing it into Masterpage's body doesn't work.. and I'm unable to place it into Cpge

Comment: after this line <script type="text/javascript"> function Slider() { $(".slider#1").show("fade", 500); } </script>

Comment: Do I place <Script> tags? Sorry for such nooby questions, I'm new to ASP.NET & JQuery altogether lol

Comment: yes you need to place the above piece of code between <script> </script> tag

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Slider();
        });
        </script>

I've done as you said, but it still doesn't load the image requested :/

Comment: then some thing wrong with your slider() function ,please check the console for errors

Comment: Thanks for your help, I resolved the issue, support was much appreciated :).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been implementing next/previous buttons.. Well it was actually really simple, but due to the resolution in the tutorial I hadn't noticed, even after checking over it several times.. It was just the fact " .Slider#1 " hadn't had a space between " .Slider " and " #1 ", so result in fixing it was " .Slider #1 ".. I could implement the <body onload="Slider();"> into MasterPage, but figured that may interfere with future projects.. So I went ahead and used your routine.. so in that case I shall vote for your answer :), thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not to use this approach.

The benefit of using jQuery is that it is unobtrusive i.e. safely separates behavior from content.

It loads without having to be intermingled with your markup (html) and when it is safe to do so i.e. when the document is ready.

I would use this instead:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  Script();
});
```

Or the shorthand version:

```
$(function(){
  Script();
});
```

And remove the javascript from your markup.

```
<body>
```

More info here:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your content page.

$(document.body).attr('onload', 'Script();');

Answer (score 0):

Write your javascript code like within 'script' tag.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   Slider();
 });

 function Slider() { 
   $(".slider#1").show("fade", 500); 
 }
```

Remove onload="Slider();" from body tag.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried implementing that and it still doesn't work :S.. Nothing's working, No idea why..

Comment: did you include jquery.min.js file in your page?

Comment: Yes the jQuery library was called for.. I figured out the problem, though Thanks for your help :), Appreciate it.